# Specifying adapter for wrapped values

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

> **Question**: Given a generic wrapper class, how can a XmlAdapter be specified on a field of this type, which should then be used to serialize the wrapped value?

### Situation: "A bag of properties"

I have a class with several generically typed members (which contain some business logic, but it boils down to typed wrapper classes for this question), which i would like to serialize while specifying the XmlAdapter of the wrapped value using an annotation on the field.

Say we have a Bag of Properties:

```
class Bag {
   public Property<TypeA> propertyA = new Property<TypeA>();
   public Property<TypeB> propertyB = new Property<TypeB>();
}

class Property<T extends Object> {
   T value;

   @XmlElement
   public T getValue()
   public T setValue(T value)
   // ...
}
```

This gets serialized/deserialized just fine as Long as TypeA or TypeB have known XmlAdapter or are serializable by definition.

```
<Bag>
   <propertyA>myAValue</propertyA>
   <property>myBValue</propertyB>
</Bag>
```

#### How to specify an Adapter for the value of a "Property"?

In some cases, the value of propertyA has to be (de)serialized using a specific XmlAdapter, e.g. because ist runtime value is created dynamically from Information in the XML.

> To specify a XmlAdapter for a member of a class, the @XmlJavaTypeAdapter Annotation can normally be used.

This process, as far as i understood, does not directly apply here.
In my case, I would like to annotate the "propertyA" field with an Adapter to be used when serializing the Propertys value (e.g. propertyA.getValue()).

Ideally, it should look like the following.

```
class Bag {
   @PropertyValueAdapter(TypeAdapterForA.class)
   public Property<TypeA> propertyA = new Property<TypeA>();
   //...
} 

// This generically adapts TypeA
class TypeAdapterForA extends XmlAdapter<Object, TypeA> {
  public TypeA unmarshal(Object element){
  // ...
}
```

However, I could not find a good way to implement this. Of course, we could implement adapter classes for every Type we want to use with a Property, which then basically just forward the Marshalling, doubling the number of Adapters. A generic way would be preferrable.

#### Mediocre Workaround

Toying around with XmlAdapters, (Un)Marshaller.Listener etc., i came up with a workaround using an XmlAdapter for the Property class, which is (aditionally) setup in the  beforeUnmarshal call to Bag, so that it has access to the annotations and can manually choose the correct marshalling. This connection, however, cannot be understood by JAXB (the model now does not correspond to the produced XML anymore).

This feels less than optimal. Besides being complex and error prone, the model does no longer correctly reflect the data; during unmarshalling, we cannot find out the target (e.g. the field in Bag into which we are unmarshalling).

So the question still  remains, given a generic wrapper class, how can a XmlAdapter be specified on a field of this type, which should then be used to serialize the wrapped value?